# Delphi 7 IDE disables some "Enhancement Modules" on Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-7

I am running Delphi 7 on Windows 7 x64. Everything is working fine except this thing.

When I start the IDE the enhancement modules for key mappings are enabled and working in the default blank project but when I load one of my projects, Delphi disables the keyboard shortcuts from my 2 installed extensions.

[image: Delphi key mapping bug]

I don't have any other extensions installed except the two visible in the above screenshot.

Do anyone have any idea how to get around this issue? It is really driving me crazy ...

Thanks a lot!

I think that it can be related to a crash. I have just installed madExcept and the IDE crashes whenever I load a project.

Exception is: EOSError with "A call to an OS function failed."

The callstack is:

```
main thread ($284):
40018cee +0007a rtl70.bpl       Sysutils     RaiseLastOSError
00834214 +00130 vcl70.bpl       Controls     TWinControl.CreateWnd
00837454 +00038 vcl70.bpl       Controls     TWinControl.AdjustSize
008345e2 +00016 vcl70.bpl       Controls     TWinControl.CreateHandle
00837334 +0001c vcl70.bpl       Controls     TWinControl.HandleNeeded
00837341 +00005 vcl70.bpl       Controls     TWinControl.GetHandle
402322e6 +001ba vclx70.bpl      Tabs         TTabSet.Paint
008391bf +00057 vcl70.bpl       Controls     TCustomControl.PaintWindow
00834e2e +0004e vcl70.bpl       Controls     TWinControl.PaintHandler
0083535b +0003f vcl70.bpl       Controls     TWinControl.WMPaint
00839158 +00010 vcl70.bpl       Controls     TCustomControl.WMPaint
00831a98 +00188 vcl70.bpl       Controls     TControl.WndProc
00834c97 +00157 vcl70.bpl       Controls     TWinControl.WndProc
00834914 +0002c vcl70.bpl       Controls     TWinControl.MainWndProc
778f0117 +0002b ntdll.dll                    KiUserCallbackDispatcher
75053598 +0003f user32.dll                   UpdateWindow
75057945 +00016 user32.dll                   CallWindowProcA
00834d7b +000d7 vcl70.bpl       Controls     TWinControl.DefaultHandler
00831a98 +00188 vcl70.bpl       Controls     TControl.WndProc
00834c97 +00157 vcl70.bpl       Controls     TWinControl.WndProc
00834914 +0002c vcl70.bpl       Controls     TWinControl.MainWndProc
778f0117 +0002b ntdll.dll                    KiUserCallbackDispatcher
75056175 +00047 user32.dll                   SendMessageA
007f4921 +00145 vcl70.bpl       Comctrls     TCustomStatusBar.UpdatePanel
007f4a64 +00100 vcl70.bpl       Comctrls     TCustomStatusBar.UpdatePanels
007f4bd4 +0000c vcl70.bpl       Comctrls     TCustomStatusBar.WMPaint
00831a98 +00188 vcl70.bpl       Controls     TControl.WndProc
00834c97 +00157 vcl70.bpl       Controls     TWinControl.WndProc
00834914 +0002c vcl70.bpl       Controls     TWinControl.MainWndProc
778f0117 +0002b ntdll.dll                    KiUserCallbackDispatcher
75057945 +00016 user32.dll                   CallWindowProcA
00834d7b +000d7 vcl70.bpl       Controls     TWinControl.DefaultHandler
00831a98 +00188 vcl70.bpl       Controls     TControl.WndProc
00834c97 +00157 vcl70.bpl       Controls     TWinControl.WndProc
00834914 +0002c vcl70.bpl       Controls     TWinControl.MainWndProc
778f0117 +0002b ntdll.dll                    KiUserCallbackDispatcher
75080d0f +2aa8a user32.dll                   CallNextHookEx
00831a98 +00188 vcl70.bpl       Controls     TControl.WndProc
00834c97 +00157 vcl70.bpl       Controls     TWinControl.WndProc
00834914 +0002c vcl70.bpl       Controls     TWinControl.MainWndProc
778f0117 +0002b ntdll.dll                    KiUserCallbackDispatcher
0083723a +0000e vcl70.bpl       Controls     TWinControl.Repaint
007f4c01 +00019 vcl70.bpl       Comctrls     TCustomStatusBar.WMSize
00831a98 +00188 vcl70.bpl       Controls     TControl.WndProc
00834c97 +00157 vcl70.bpl       Controls     TWinControl.WndProc
00834914 +0002c vcl70.bpl       Controls     TWinControl.MainWndProc
778f0117 +0002b ntdll.dll                    KiUserCallbackDispatcher
75057945 +00016 user32.dll                   CallWindowProcA
00834d7b +000d7 vcl70.bpl       Controls     TWinControl.DefaultHandler
0083218c +0000c vcl70.bpl       Controls     TControl.WMWindowPosChanged
008356fe +00096 vcl70.bpl       Controls     TWinControl.WMWindowPosChanged
00831a98 +00188 vcl70.bpl       Controls     TControl.WndProc
00834c97 +00157 vcl70.bpl       Controls     TWinControl.WndProc
00834914 +0002c vcl70.bpl       Controls     TWinControl.MainWndProc
778f0117 +0002b ntdll.dll                    KiUserCallbackDispatcher
008338db +000b7 vcl70.bpl       Controls     TWinControl.AlignControls
0083398b +00063 vcl70.bpl       Controls     TWinControl.AlignControl
008339e6 +00002 vcl70.bpl       Controls     TWinControl.Realign
00835790 +00018 vcl70.bpl       Controls     TWinControl.WMSize
00831a98 +00188 vcl70.bpl       Controls     TControl.WndProc
00834c97 +00157 vcl70.bpl       Controls     TWinControl.WndProc
00834914 +0002c vcl70.bpl       Controls     TWinControl.MainWndProc
778f0117 +0002b ntdll.dll                    KiUserCallbackDispatcher
75057945 +00016 user32.dll                   CallWindowProcA
00834d7b +000d7 vcl70.bpl       Controls     TWinControl.DefaultHandler
0083218c +0000c vcl70.bpl       Controls     TControl.WMWindowPosChanged
008356fe +00096 vcl70.bpl       Controls     TWinControl.WMWindowPosChanged
007cee41 +000d5 vcl70.bpl       Extctrls     TCustomPanel.WMWindowPosChanged
00831a98 +00188 vcl70.bpl       Controls     TControl.WndProc
00834c97 +00157 vcl70.bpl       Controls     TWinControl.WndProc
00834914 +0002c vcl70.bpl       Controls     TWinControl.MainWndProc
778f0117 +0002b ntdll.dll                    KiUserCallbackDispatcher
008338ae +0008a vcl70.bpl       Controls     TWinControl.AlignControls
0083398b +00063 vcl70.bpl       Controls     TWinControl.AlignControl
008339e6 +00002 vcl70.bpl       Controls     TWinControl.Realign
00835790 +00018 vcl70.bpl       Controls     TWinControl.WMSize
00831a98 +00188 vcl70.bpl       Controls     TControl.WndProc
00834c97 +00157 vcl70.bpl       Controls     TWinControl.WndProc
00834914 +0002c vcl70.bpl       Controls     TWinControl.MainWndProc
778f0117 +0002b ntdll.dll                    KiUserCallbackDispatcher
75057945 +00016 user32.dll                   CallWindowProcA
00834d7b +000d7 vcl70.bpl       Controls     TWinControl.DefaultHandler
0083218c +0000c vcl70.bpl       Controls     TControl.WMWindowPosChanged
008356fe +00096 vcl70.bpl       Controls     TWinControl.WMWindowPosChanged
007cee41 +000d5 vcl70.bpl       Extctrls     TCustomPanel.WMWindowPosChanged
00831a98 +00188 vcl70.bpl       Controls     TControl.WndProc
00834c97 +00157 vcl70.bpl       Controls     TWinControl.WndProc
00834914 +0002c vcl70.bpl       Controls     TWinControl.MainWndProc
778f0117 +0002b ntdll.dll                    KiUserCallbackDispatcher
00831868 +00024 vcl70.bpl       Controls     TControl.Perform
0082fafe +0008a vcl70.bpl       Controls     TControl.SetBounds
008338c9 +000a5 vcl70.bpl       Controls     TWinControl.AlignControls
0084c86a +00016 vcl70.bpl       Forms        TScrollingWinControl.AlignControls
0084eb0e +0000e vcl70.bpl       Forms        TCustomForm.AlignControls
0083398b +00063 vcl70.bpl       Controls     TWinControl.AlignControl
0082f8cc +00008 vcl70.bpl       Controls     TControl.RequestAlign
00837454 +00038 vcl70.bpl       Controls     TWinControl.AdjustSize
0083391d +000f9 vcl70.bpl       Controls     TWinControl.AlignControls
0083398b +00063 vcl70.bpl       Controls     TWinControl.AlignControl
008339e6 +00002 vcl70.bpl       Controls     TWinControl.Realign
00835790 +00018 vcl70.bpl       Controls     TWinControl.WMSize
00831a98 +00188 vcl70.bpl       Controls     TControl.WndProc
00834c97 +00157 vcl70.bpl       Controls     TWinControl.WndProc
0083bc63 +003bf vcl70.bpl       Controls     TDockTree.WindowProc
00834914 +0002c vcl70.bpl       Controls     TWinControl.MainWndProc
778f0117 +0002b ntdll.dll                    KiUserCallbackDispatcher
75057945 +00016 user32.dll                   CallWindowProcA
00834d7b +000d7 vcl70.bpl       Controls     TWinControl.DefaultHandler
0083218c +0000c vcl70.bpl       Controls     TControl.WMWindowPosChanged
008356fe +00096 vcl70.bpl       Controls     TWinControl.WMWindowPosChanged
007cee41 +000d5 vcl70.bpl       Extctrls     TCustomPanel.WMWindowPosChanged
00831a98 +00188 vcl70.bpl       Controls     TControl.WndProc
00834c97 +00157 vcl70.bpl       Controls     TWinControl.WndProc
0083bc63 +003bf vcl70.bpl       Controls     TDockTree.WindowProc
00834914 +0002c vcl70.bpl       Controls     TWinControl.MainWndProc
778f0117 +0002b ntdll.dll                    KiUserCallbackDispatcher
0082fc87 +00013 vcl70.bpl       Controls     TControl.SetWidth
00943216 +0004a designide70.bpl Idedockpanel TEditorDockPanel.CMDockNotification
00831a98 +00188 vcl70.bpl       Controls     TControl.WndProc
00834c97 +00157 vcl70.bpl       Controls     TWinControl.WndProc
0083bc63 +003bf vcl70.bpl       Controls     TDockTree.WindowProc
00831868 +00024 vcl70.bpl       Controls     TControl.Perform
00837179 +00009 vcl70.bpl       Controls     TWinControl.Invalidate
0083bc63 +003bf vcl70.bpl       Controls     TDockTree.WindowProc
00831868 +00024 vcl70.bpl       Controls     TControl.Perform
008300d5 +00055 vcl70.bpl       Controls     TControl.SendDockNotification
00831a8d +0017d vcl70.bpl       Controls     TControl.WndProc
00834c97 +00157 vcl70.bpl       Controls     TWinControl.WndProc
0084e87d +00421 vcl70.bpl       Forms        TCustomForm.WndProc
008303a7 +0003b vcl70.bpl       Controls     TControl.SetClientSize
00831868 +00024 vcl70.bpl       Controls     TControl.Perform
00830427 +00027 vcl70.bpl       Controls     TControl.SetVisible
0084e372 +0003a vcl70.bpl       Forms        TCustomForm.SetVisible
00944cf6 +002ce designide70.bpl Deskform     TDesktopForm.LoadWindowState
00945ff3 +00067 designide70.bpl Dockform     TDockableForm.LoadWindowState
00586e44 +000b8 coreide70.bpl   Editors      TEditWindow.LoadDesktopFormInstances
0050896a +00036 coreide70.bpl   Desktop      TDesktopState.Load
005084cf +0003b coreide70.bpl   Desktop      TDesktopStates.LoadDesktop
0055e332 +0015a coreide70.bpl   Modules      CreateProjectClass
00512d3c +000a0 coreide70.bpl   Docmodul     TFilterList.OpenFile
005145e7 +0002b coreide70.bpl   Docmodul     CallDefaultOpenProc
00831a98 +00188 vcl70.bpl       Controls     TControl.WndProc
00834c97 +00157 vcl70.bpl       Controls     TWinControl.WndProc
0084e87d +00421 vcl70.bpl       Forms        TCustomForm.WndProc
778f0117 +0002b ntdll.dll                    KiUserCallbackDispatcher
00834914 +0002c vcl70.bpl       Controls     TWinControl.MainWndProc
75047bc5 +0000a user32.dll                   DispatchMessageA
0085568b +00083 vcl70.bpl       Forms        TApplication.ProcessMessage
008556aa +0000a vcl70.bpl       Forms        TApplication.ProcessMessages
008805a9 +0000d vcl70.bpl       Appevnts     TCustomApplicationEvents.DoActivate
00854f26 +0055a vcl70.bpl       Forms        TApplication.WndProc
75047bc5 +0000a user32.dll                   DispatchMessageA
0085568b +00083 vcl70.bpl       Forms        TApplication.ProcessMessage
008556c2 +0000a vcl70.bpl       Forms        TApplication.HandleMessage
008558f2 +00096 vcl70.bpl       Forms        TApplication.Run
765233c8 +00010 kernel32.dll                 BaseThreadInitThunk
```

Answer (score 2):

It's seems that Delphi 7 have some problems if installed in program files (x86) !!!

I know that it sounds strange, look at this [blog post](http://weblog.hansotten.com/?p=833)

Comment: I don't think it is so. I've had used Delphi 7 before on Windows 7 x64 machine and it doesn't manifested the described bug there. Must be something about this installation but I cannot figure out what ...

Comment: I've got Delphi 6 installed in that location and there are no problems. I know D6 and D7 aren't identical but they are pretty darn close.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how the Delphi 6 and neither Delphi7, but I think it's going to a conflict between the servers of the two versions of Delphi IDE 6 and 7. Correct me if I'm wrong!

Try disabling the oldest in the case, and and then activate the D6 D7! just to test!

Good Luck!